# How to check if a record exists in an Access database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, authentication, oledb

I'm trying a new approach for a project that I'm working on and I'm just starting to learn about Access Databases. I using **VB.net** and my question is: How do you see if a record exists in the table of the database. I thought I had it understood but that is not the case. I'm creating a login and I want it to check if the Username that they typed in exists before it tries to compare what you typed with what's in the database. I see alot of questions on how to do this...but not for VB.net *and* MS Access

Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class LoginForm1
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim Errors As String
    Public Sub AccessAccountDatabase()
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        dataFile = "C:\Users\Richard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CybSol Journal Database\CybSol Journal Database\cgi-bin\Data.mdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        Errors = ""
        Try
            myConnection.Open()
            Dim str As String
            str = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Username='" & UsernameTxt.Text & "' AND Password='" & PasswordTxt.Text & "'"
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dr.Read()

            If UsernameTxt.Text = dr("Username").ToString AndAlso PasswordTxt.Text = dr("Password").ToString Then
                Dim Welcome As String = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Real_Name=" & "Username"
                MsgBox("Welcome back " & dr("Real_Name") & "!")
            Else
                MsgBox("Login Failure")
            End If
            myConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub OkayBtn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles OkayBtn.Click
        AccessAccountDatabase()
    End Sub
End Class
```

So now my question is... How do you get it to check if a record exists in the database, because when you type in the correct information (The correct username and password that exists in the database) it says welcome and all. But when you type in the wrong Username and/or Password it doesn't work. Without the "Try Catch" statement the program just freezes. With the try catch it states this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No data exists for the row/column.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.DoValueCheck(Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.GetValue(Int32 ordinal)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.get_Item(String name)
   at CybSol_Journal_Database.LoginForm1.AccessAccountDatabase() in c:\users\richard\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\CybSol Journal Database\CybSol Journal Database\LoginForm1.vb:line 36
```

Addition information: line 36 is this: `If UsernameTxt.Text = dr("Username").ToString AndAlso PasswordTxt.Text = dr("Password").ToString Then`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First problem:

[PASSWORD is a reserved keyword](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) in Access. You should encapsulate in square brackets:

```
"SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Username='" & UsernameTxt.Text & _
"' AND [Password]='" & PasswordTxt.Text & "'"
```

Second problem:

NEVER use string concatenation to create sql text. ALWAYS use parameters

```
 str = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Username=? AND [Password]=?"   
 Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)   
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", UserNameTxt.Text)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", PasswordTxt.Text)
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Why? [look here](http://xkcd.com/327/) what could happen if you concatenate strings from user input

Third problem: Test if your command returns rows

```
 If dr.Read() Then
    ......

 End if
```

Comment: Fourth problem: Don't store the password. Store a seeded hash of the password

Comment: And also. In case of exception, the connection is not closed (see Holger Brandt answer for the medicine)

Comment: Thank you so much Steve, you really helped me out and helped me understand alot more. You have really been a big help in understand my project and Access. So again, thank you :)

Comment: If you test it with '.Read()' and there are no rows you will get an exception. Better use '.HasRows' as per the answer below.

Comment: @yu_ominae Read() return false if there are no rows

Comment: Dammit, you're right I was getting something else wrong. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @Steve, way late, sorry, but finally removed it :)

Answer (score 2):

I added some `Using` statements so you don't have to manually close the connections. Also, I parameterized the SQL statement to prevent SQL Injection.

```
 Public Class LoginForm1
      Dim provider As String
      Dim dataFile As String
      Dim connString As String
      'Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
      'Public dr As OleDbDataReader
      Dim Errors As String
      Public Sub AccessAccountDatabase()
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        dataFile = "C:\Users\Richard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CybSol Journal Database\CybSol Journal Database\cgi-bin\Data.mdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        Errors = ""
        Try
          Using myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connString)
            myConnection.Open()
            Dim str As String
            str = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Username=@USER AND [Password]=@PWD "
            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER", UsernameTxt.Text)
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PWD", PasswordTxt.Text)
              Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If dr.HasRows Then
                  dr.Read()
                  If UsernameTxt.Text = dr("Username").ToString AndAlso PasswordTxt.Text = dr("Password").ToString Then
                    Dim Welcome As String = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Real_Name=" & "Username"
                    MsgBox("Welcome back " & dr("Real_Name") & "!")
                  Else
                    MsgBox("Login Failure")
                  End If
                Else
                  MsgBox("Login Failure")
                End If
              End Using
            End Using
          End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
          MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try


      End Sub

      Private Sub OkayBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OkayBtn.Click
        AccessAccountDatabase()
      End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: The line `myConnection.ConnectionString = connString` seems to be unnecessary (I've tested the code in my application). `myConnection` is not yet defined at that point. Anyway, that's a very nice code piece :)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  The `OleDbDataReader.Read` returns a boolean indicating whether or not it successfully read an existing row.  Therefore, you can check to see if it returned `True` before trying to read the record.  For instance:

```
If dr.Read() Then
    If UsernameTxt.Text = dr("Username").ToString AndAlso PasswordTxt.Text = dr("Password").ToString Then
    Dim Welcome As String = "SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE Real_Name=" & "Username"
        MsgBox("Welcome back " & dr("Real_Name") & "!")
    Else
        MsgBox("Login Failure")
    End If
End If
```

Also, I feel I should at least mention that storing a password in plain text is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check for the username and password in your code again since if does not match in the database, no rows will be returned.

You can simply do

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
If dr.HasRows Then
   //it matched
Else
   //it didn't match. could not log in
End If
```

Your approach is below if you still want to keep it but it's not necessary

```
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
If dr.HasRows Then

    dr.Read()

    If UsernameTxt.Text = dr("Username").ToString AndAlso PasswordTxt.Text = dr("Password").ToString Then

    Else

    End If

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Read() method on your DataReader (note that this keeps your connection to the database open and you'll be unable to execute any other commands on the database while your DataReader is still Reading.

```
If String.Compare(dr("Username").ToString(), UsernameTxt.Text, true) AndAlso String.Compare(dr("Password").ToString(), PasswordTxt.Text.ToString() Then
    ' The username and password for the record match
    ' the input from the login form
    ProcessLogin()
Else
    ' Invalid username or password, send an error
End If
```