# Alert of duplicate name in Access 2003, despite a duplicate I want to decide if include it or not

Tags: ms-access, duplicates

I have a table with this fields:

```
ID(Autonumeric)
Name(Text)
```

And I have a form, this form has a TextBox for input the name.

Example of input

```
1.John
2.Katie
```

As soon I finish input the name in the TextBox, I want to show an alert that show if the record is duplicated.

Example:

If I input again:

```
3.Katie
```

The program needs to show me a message like this: *"Duplicate name, do you want to save it or not?"*

Comment: Are you trying to ask us how to query for a value in the database?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to search in a table in the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a record exists in an Access database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511493/how-to-check-if-a-record-exists-in-an-access-database)

Answer (score 1):

Use the text box's *Before Update* event to check whether its current value is already stored in your table.

If your text box is named *txtName* and *YourTable* is the table which contains the *Name* field, this should do what you want:

```vb
Private Sub txtName_BeforeUpdate(ByRef Cancel As Integer)
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strSelect As String

    strSelect = "SELECT Count(*) FROM YourTable WHERE [Name]=[which_name];"
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSelect)
    qdf.Parameters("which_name").Value = Me!txtName.Value
    If qdf.OpenRecordset()(0) > 0 Then
        If MsgBox("Duplicate name, do you want to save it or not?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

When a match is found, and the user clicks "No" at the `MsgBox`, the next line .. `Cancel = True` ... aborts the text box value update, leaving the cursor in the text box.  The user must change the text box value or agree to store the duplicate value before they can proceed past that text box.